Alexa json retrieval from S3
So, I'm using the custom deployment template for Alexa. I've just started out coding with Alexa, but I have Python experience.
I'm just playing around with the boilerplate code provided. I'm testing with the helloworld intent just to get to grip with things. I have searched and looked at the Alexa tutorials, but they're more for images and sounds. I'm looking specifically at static data. With it being static, I don't want to use dynamoDB. I may have other uses for that and to stay on the free tier, I'll save my limited dynamoDB allocation for later.
So, with this code I don't get any errors loading the test JSON.
class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        json_url = create_presigned_url("Media/json_data/test.json")
        test_raw_data = requests.get(json_url).content
        test_json_data = json.loads(test_raw_data)
        print(test_json_data)
        speak_output = "Hello World"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )

I get the following in the cloudwatch logs.
{'test1': 'test one output', 'test2': 'test two output', 'test3': [{'test4': 'test four output', 'test44': 'test fourty four output', 'test444': 'test four hundred and forty four output'}]}

If I try and reference the data with print (test_json_data.test1). I get the sorry message from Alex and the following Python traceback in cloudwatch.
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'test1'

So, that says to me that it is actually a string, not a JSON probably due to encoding, but why don't get an error on JSON loads? The boilerplate code for the presigned is:
def create_presigned_url(object_name):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object with a capped expiration of 60 seconds

    :param object_name: string
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             region_name=os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_REGION'),
                             config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4',s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
    try:
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET')
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=60*1)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response


I'm an idiot been coding something else for a while and forgot how python works. No dot notation.
